# Create-React-App on Lightsail: DNS and SSL issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, ssl, dns

I'm trying to deploy a CRA on Lightsail and I'm having issues with the SSL cert and DNS.

I have tested the A record with no errors. http://52.40.123.5:3000/ displays my react app but abechoi.com does not, even if I click on advanced.

I added "homepage": "http://abechoi.com", no change.

As for the SSL, I found a free cert.pem and key.pem off a website and I tried running "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=cert.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=key.pem npm start", no change, possibly because the domain name has issues.

Anyways, if anyone could offer some kind of help, I would greatly appreciate it. From what I've read AWS Amplify is easier but I want more experience working my way around a Linux CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can issue a Free SSL using let's encrypt and then use it for your node command line:

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress

ignore the Wordpress part here, you just need to get the pem files and hook it to node

Comment: Thank you, will do!

Comment: cool, please let me know if it's all good and a reminder to vote the answer and mark It as resolved